# ADO.NET transaction requirements for inserting stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, transactions, ado.net

I've got a stored procedure that simply inserts a new recort to a table. The application uses multiple threads to work with the DB.
Should I wrap my `SqlCommand` into a transaction in ADO.NET to avoid primary key violation?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("<some connection string"))
{
  connection.Open();
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("StoredProcName", connection))
  {
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
   {
     command.Transaction = transaction;
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     transaction.Commit();
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code that you currently have..with the exception I do not see any 'RollBack()` code nor a try{}catch{} block when doing `command.ExecuteNonQuery.. also why not wrap the transaction code on the DB server side.. also if you want to track the transaction you could use the overload and name the actual transaction.. but for now I do not see any real issues with what you have..

Comment: What is your primary key? Assuming you are not using an identity column, as far as I know the only way to avoid a race condition is to use `MERGE` along with the `HOLDLOCK` hint, so you would need to alter the procedure itself. This in itself then prevents further issues with [potential deadlocks](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23467/merge-statement-deadlocking-itself)

Comment: @GarethD, If I use identity column can I forget about race conditions when inserting records from multiple threads? I mean one table, PK column is also identity column.

Comment: You can, but if you need some other combination of fields to be unique then you would still encounter issues. For example, if you have a table of Users, and have an identity column `UserID` on your table, the you may also wish to constrain another column `UserName` to be unique. So while Identity will ensure that there are no primary key violations on `UserID`, it doesn't ensure that you won't get a unique constraint/index violation on `Username`.

Comment: What I was really getting at is how your primary key is generated. This quite often pops up as an issue when people are trying to generate their own key in a certain format, such as incorporating the date into an ID, or simply prefixing an ID with something, so you end up with a primary key with values  "User00001", "User00002" etc. More often than not, there is a better solution for the key generation, rather than trying to safeguard the existing process that generates it with transactions.

Comment: @GarethD, thank you! You've helped me a lot.